# Magento enterprise CMS request_url not updating

Tags: magento

**Using Magento 1.14.2**

I am not sure if anyone had this issue before but when I update a URL key in Magento Enterprise CMS the changes are not taking effect in the tree.

Example: When test page's URL key is updated from test to test-1, I can still access http://test.com/someparent/test.html. Tried loading http://test.com/someparent/test-1.html and it comes up as 404 page not found.

**My investigation so far:**

- When URL key is updated identifier field in cms_page is updated but not in enterprise_cms_hierachy_node (request_url key).
- Went a bit further to look at the code and found that in app/core/Enterprise/Cms/Model/Hierarchy/Node appendPageToNodes()

  if ($node->getPageExists()) {
                  continue;
              } else {
                  $node->addData($pageData)
                      ->setParentNodeId($node->getId())
                      ->unsetData($this->getIdFieldName())
                      ->setLevel($node->getLevel() + 1)
                      ->setSortOrder($sortOrder)
                      ->setRequestUrl($node->getRequestUrl() . '/' . $page->getIdentifier())
                      ->setXpath($node->getXpath() . '/')
                      ->save();
              }

So, if page node exists it does nothing and moves on. Where as if doesnt exist it inserts new record.

Just wanted to know if any others have experienced this issue and what did you do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below, You will knock it off.

1. Take a backup of your database in .sql file using mysqldump command
2. Truncate the table **core_url_rewrite** in your database
3. Now refresh the magento home page.
4. Check weather the rows added to **core_url_rewrite** table.

You are done!.